# MongoDB: compare nested arrays and delete single entries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to delete every entry in the array "moduleOne_data", if the child element "years" of the "moduleOne_data" entry differs from the array "currentYears".

What I do have:

```
{
  _id : ObjectId("5a8d2f803d516722fcf94fd1"),
  name : "testName",
  appData : {
    moduleOne : {
        moduleOne_data : [ 
            {
                date : "20180221-1",
                years : [ 
                    2013, 
                    2014, 
                    2015, 
                    2016, 
                    2017
                ],
                status : "done"
            }, 
            {
                date : "20180221-2",
                years : [ 
                    2013, 
                    2014, 
                    2015, 
                    2016
                ],
                status : "done"
            }, 
            {
                date : "20180221-3",
                years : [ 
                    2013, 
                    2014, 
                    2015
                ],
                status : "done"
            }
        ],
        currentYears : {
            years : [ 
                2013, 
                2014, 
                2015, 
                2016
            ]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

In my example the years of the second entry in the array "moduleOne_data" match the years of the "currentYears" array. So I want to delete the first and the third entry.

What I want after the update:

```
{
  _id : ObjectId("5a8d2f803d516722fcf94fd1"),
  name : "testName",
  appData : {
    moduleOne : {
        moduleOne_data : [ 
            {
                date : "20180221-2",
                years : [ 
                    2013, 
                    2014, 
                    2015, 
                    2016
                ],
                status : "done"
            }
        ],
        currentYears : {
            years : [ 
                2013, 
                2014, 
                2015, 
                2016
            ]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: What I tried so far:

```
for (j = 0; j < appData.moduleOne.moduleOne_data.length; j++) {
  db.collection.update(
    {"_id":ObjectId("5a8d2f803d516722fcf94fd1")},
    { $pull: { "appData.moduleOne.moduleOne_data" : { years: { $not: appData.moduleOne.currentYears.years } } } }
  );
}
```

Comment: What have you tired so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
db.getCollection('collection').update({
    "_id": ObjectId("5a8d70d3bc3e6b9f2d5994c0")
}, {
    "$pull": {
        "appData.moduleOne.moduleOne_data": {
            "years": {
                "$ne": [
                    2013,
                    2014,
                    2015,
                    2016
                ]
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Did not work. I also want to compare it to the "years" array of the "currentYears" Object

Comment: Do you want to use mongoose?

Comment: It works for me, maybe you are passing the wrong id.

Comment: Yes, I want to use mongoose. But if I get a solution for MongoDB it will be easy to transfer it to a mongoose solution I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get currentYears in the same query. but you can find records and get currentYears and use this query.